# bitnami consul cannot access file or directory using docker desktop volume mount

Tags: linux, windows, docker, bitnami, consul

Running Consul with docker desktop using windows containers and experimental mode turned on works well. However if I try mounting bitnami consul's datafile to a local volume mount I get the following error:

`chown: cannot access '/bitnami/consul'`

[image: powershell chown error]

My compose file looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  consul:
    image: bitnami/consul:latest
    volumes:
      - ${USERPROFILE}\DockerVolumes\consul:/bitnami
    ports:
      - '8300:8300'
      - '8301:8301'
      - '8301:8301/udp'
      - '8500:8500'
      - '8600:8600'
      - '8600:8600/udp'
    networks: 
      nat:        
        aliases:
          - consul
```

If I remove the volumes part, everything works just fine, but I cannot persist my data. If followed instructions in the [readme file](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-consul#persisting-your-application). The speak of having the proper permissions, but I do not know how to get that to work using docker desktop.

**Side note**
If I do not mount `/bitnami` but `/bitnami/consul`, I get the following error:
`2020-03-30T14:59:00.327Z [ERROR] agent: Error starting agent: error="Failed to start Consul server: Failed to start Raft: invalid argument"`
[image: powershell failed to start Raft]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to edit the docker-compose.yaml to deploy the consul container as root by adding the `user: root` directive:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  consul:
    image: bitnami/consul:latest
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ${USERPROFILE}\DockerVolumes\consul:/bitnami
    ports:
      - '8300:8300'
      - '8301:8301'
      - '8301:8301/udp'
      - '8500:8500'
      - '8600:8600'
      - '8600:8600/udp'
    networks: 
      nat:        
        aliases:
          - consul
```

Without `user: root` the container is executed as non-root (user 1001):

```
▶ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                              NAMES
0c590d7df611        bitnami/consul:1    "/opt/bitnami/script…"   4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:8300-8301->8300-8301/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8500->8500/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8301->8301/udp, 0.0.0.0:8600->8600/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8600->8600/udp   bitnami-docker-consul_consul_1

▶ dcexec 0c590d7df611
I have no name!@0c590d7df611:/$ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1001
```

But adding this line the container is executed as `root`:

```
▶ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                              NAMES
ac206b56f57b        bitnami/consul:1    "/opt/bitnami/script…"   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:8300-8301->8300-8301/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8500->8500/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8301->8301/udp, 0.0.0.0:8600->8600/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8600->8600/udp   bitnami-docker-consul_consul_1

▶ dcexec ac206b56f57b
root@ac206b56f57b:/# whoami
root
```

If the container is executed as `root` there shouldn't be any issue with the permissions in the host volume.

Comment: This does not work, I'm still getting the error `chown: cannot access '/bitnami/consul': No such file or directory`. If i create the folder `consul` in my mounted directory and restart the container I get `Failed to start Consul server: Failed to start Raft: invalid argument`. Did you actually get consul running on Windows?

Comment: I personally don't have a Windows environment, sorry. You also can try using Docker volumes instead of local paths. That is the configuration you can see in this `docker-compose.yaml`: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-consul/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

Consul container is a [non-root container](https://engineering.bitnami.com/articles/why-non-root-containers-are-important-for-security.html), in those cases, the non-root user should be able to write in the volume.

Using host directories as a volume you need to ensure that the directory you are mounting into the container has the proper permissions, in that case, writable permission for `others`. You can modify the permission by running `sudo chmod o+x ${USERPROFILE}\DockerVolumes\consul` (or the correct path to the host directory).

This local folder is created the first time you run `docker-compose up` or you can create it by yourself with `mkdir`. Once created (manually or automatically) you should give the proper permissions with `chmod`.

I am not familiar with Docker desktop nor Windows environments, but you should be able to do the equivalent actions using a CLI.

Comment: I think the problem is in setting the lack of having `chmod` commands for windows, so you can not chown or chmod on the volume from within the container. I already tried setting permissions in windows to all for everyone.